# Prevent interruption of wand display method on Raspbian

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, wand

I am using wand library in my raspberry project running raspbian and python 2.7.

I have a code part as below to display picture from an url:

```
with Image(file=urllib2.urlopen(r.text)) as imageOBJ:
    display(imageOBJ)
```

These lines display the image correctly. However, I want this window to stay open and my process to continue with other things in my script. Because after 30 seconds I want to repeat the same thing and change the image in the window. Right now, my code is not running until I close the display window.

Please note that this is not the case on my mac but only on raspberry pi B+ , wheezy raspbian.

How can I prevent this behaviour without closing the image display window?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is expected as both Windows & OS X call the OS's run command `start` & `open` respectively -- [see reference](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/blob/master/wand/display.py#L58). On the Raspberry Pi, and other like systems, the [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) library calls [MagickDisplayImage](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickDisplayImage) directly on Python's *MainThread*.

To emulate like behavior on the Raspberry Pi use the [xdg-open](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) utility, and Python's `subprocess` and `tmpfile` modules.

1. Create a temporary file to hold the image
2. Write image to temporary file
3. Call `xdg-open` to open temporary file in an isolated process.

```py
import subprocess, tempfile
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='wizard:') as imageOBJ:
    tempOBJ = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.jpg',
                                          prefix='/tmp/myProject-',
                                          delete=False)
    imageOBJ.save(file=tempOBJ)
    subprocess.call('xdg-open {}'.format(tempOBJ.name), shell=True)
```

Of course mileage will vary across OS distro/version/desktop-environment.

Comment: Sounds pretty convenient. I will try as soon as possible and check this as answer if it works. Thanks.

Comment: hi, how can I use my imageOBJ  that I'm creating with "urllib2.urlopen(r.text)" with this approach?

Comment: @SühaBoncukçu Updated example to match expected variable names, and switch kwargs.

Comment: So sorry to bother that much but I'm kinda noob when it comes to python image and file libraries. with this line : "urllib2.urlopen(r.text)" I open an url from web and getting it as an image right? I can't understand how can I convert the url to an image like this. Because when I change 'wizard:' to "urllib2.urlopen(r.text)" it says a string is expected. I'm a bit lost to be honest. Cheers!

Comment: The `file` kwarg is expecting a file object, and `filename` is a string. [See docs](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.0/wand/image.html#wand.image.Image). This `wizard:` is [a built-in filename for ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#builtin-images). I opted to use the `wizard:` in my answer's example as it's safe across all environments.

Comment: Your answer is being so helpful so far to learn new things. However, even with `wizard:` filename my script throws a syntax error on raspberry pi : `/bin/sh:  1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected` Do you think it is related? When I use `display()` method I don't get this error.

Comment: I used fbi to display image which is more suitable for me. And fixed your solution with `format(tempOBJ.name)`  Please update but I'm marking this one as an answer. Thanks.